# ¿como obtengo una lista de vectores desde una lista de gameobject[]?

Tags: array, unity3d

estoy teniendo una interrogante, para mi que estoy aprendiendo se me hace dificl, quizas para otros sea facil.

estoy usando una lista de objetos instaciados en unity3d (gameobjects[])!
basicamente lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de instanciar un objeto nuevo, este se suma a la lista de arrays, y automaticamente se cree una lista de vector3 para definir su posicion...

la lista de objetos no tiene un limite, pueden ser solamente 4 objetos o quizas 350..
varia segun cuantos objetos instancio manualmente.

de forma que si instancio 4 objetos, quede algo similar en la lista de objetos.

obj0 = x(1.235), y(0.015),z(-0.789) 
obj1 = x(2.785), y(0.237),z(-2.943)
obj2 = x(1.382), y(0.824),z(-5.158)
obj3 = x(4.125), y(0.697),z(-6.437)

que el valor lo saque automaticamente al instanciar el objeto, y que esa posicion siga siendo la misma al instanciar un nuevo objeto.

luego quiero seleccionar ese objeto y movilizarlo automaticamente, y que su valor se actualice segun cambie el valor...

para mi es dificil porque estoy metiendome en estas ecuaciones, pero quizas con algo de ayuda pueda hacerlo!

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar la lista por medio de un foreach
Ejemplo.

```
Foreach (Vector3 pos in gameobjects)
{
  pos = gameobtjects.transform.position; //igualas la variable Vector3 creada en el foreach a su Transform.position que es un Vector3
  myListVector.Add(pos); //Agregas el valor de la variable a la lista de Vector3
}
```

Esto te puede ser de ayuda.
Puedes consultar en la documentacion de Unity3D [Tranform.position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html)
y en la documentacion de Microsoft C# [Foreach](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Tambien podrias usar solo una lista y con esa administrar lo que necesites. (Pero todo depende del caso)